# Continuity of a rational function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=\dfrac{2x+1}{x^2+ax+1}$. Find the value(s) of $a$ so that $f(x)$ is continuous on all real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

Here, I'll write my attempt. The denominator $x^2+ax+1 \neq 0$. Then by using the quadratic formula, we obtain the following equation $\dfrac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2} \neq 0$. That means $-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4} \neq 0$. Then $-a = \pm \sqrt{a^2-4}$. By squaring both sides, we obtain $a^2 \neq a^2-4$ which is always true. So the conclusion is that $a$ is any real number. Your comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: The quadratic formula doesn't give that $\dfrac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2} \neq 0$, but instead that $\dfrac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2} \neq x$.

Answer (score 1):

The case you want is that $x^2+ax+1\neq0$ on the real line, which is equivalent to saying that $x^2+ax+1$ has complex roots

Comment: I just study the roots on the real line. So what $a$ can be?

Comment: @user113715: for what values of $a$ does the quadratic formula indicate there are no real roots?

Comment: Offtopic: @user113715 I visited your profile, is there any reason why you learned knot theory prior to quadratic polynomials?

Comment: I see, the quadratic formula gives no real number if $a^2-4 <0$. That means if $a \in (-2,2)$. This gives that $a \in (-\infty,-2] \cup (2,+\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

you need to be very careful with your inequalities, since for example setting setting $a=-2$ yields that $x=2$ is a solution of your denominator. In particular you need not look for $\neq 0$ but you need to look for $\neq x$, since the existence of a soltion to your quadratic equation would yield to a zero of the denominator. Hence if you pick $a$ such that $a^2<4$ you are done, since then your squareroot does not exist in $\mathbb{R}$ (pictorially your parabola does not touch the x axis), and so the fraction is defined everywhere.

Comment: ah yes, sorry, I am quite bad with the directions of my inequalities myself.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple counterexample would be choosing $a = 2$.

$$x^2+2x+1 \neq 0 \implies (x+1)^2 \neq 0 \implies x\neq -1$$

Thus, $a \in \mathbb{R}$ isn’t correct.

Your error is that you used the quadratic formula incorrectly.

$$ax^2+bx+c = 0 \implies \color{blue}{x} = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

You used $\color{red}{0}$ instead of $\color{blue}{x}$ in your inequality.

$$x^2+ax+1 \neq 0$$
$$x \neq \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}$$

If you think about the function $f(x) = x^2+ax+1$, what value of $a$ would produce no solutions (a.k.a $x$-intercepts)? The discriminant must become negative.

$$\Delta < 0 \implies a^2-4 < 0 \implies a^2 < 4 \implies a < 2 \text{ and } a > -2 \implies a \in (-2, 2)$$

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: In reply to Nick Liu commnet, There is no link actually between my question about quadratic polynomial and my research area (knot theory). Someone asked me this question and I got confused, so I posted my question here. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You're interpreting the quadratic formula in a wrong way: asking for
$$
\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}\ne0
$$
is imposing that the polynomial doesn't have $0$ among its roots, which is surely true for every $a$, because the product of the roots is $1$ (Viète's formulas). So no wonder you found that your inequation is satisfied for every value of $a$.

You rather want to impose that the polynomial $x^2+ax+1$ has *no real root*. Whenever $a^2\ge4$ there *are* real roots given by the quadratic formula. So you want $a^-4<0$, that is $-2<a<2$.

Comment: Thank you so much egreg, got it.